# how to reference metadata in a pyproject.toml file?

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I was previously using setup.py to package my Python libs. As it seems pyproject.toml is the future way of setuptools I decided to migrate before my next releases.

In setup.py I was using the following string to define the link to the downloadable tarball:

```py
setup(
    version = "2.13.4"
    download_url = "https://github.com/xx/xx/archive/v${metadata:version}.tar.gz" 
)
```

My objective is to set up the version number just once. Is it still possible in pyproject.toml and if yes how ?

I tried the following but it's not included the version parameter in the url:

```ini
[project]
version = "2.13.4"

[project.urls]
Download = "https://github.com/xx/xx/archive/v${metadata:version}.tar.gz"
```

Comment: I guess, typically you would use an extra tool that takes care of updating the version string everywhere necessary. Maybe something like [this](https://pypi.org/project/bump-release/), and I am quite sure there are other similar tools. Surprisingly `setuptools-scm` does not seem to be able to do this.

Comment: toml files do not support variables by design.

Comment: I use commitizen to update version string (including the toml) the problem here is to use the version number in a string.

Comment: yes toml don't support variables, but cfg neither. the code was interpreted by setuptool to make it work anyway.